# How to prove that maximal independent set is equal to maximum independent set in an interval graph?

Tags: graph-theory

**Introduction:**
An interval graph $IG$ is a set of intervals on the line, the corresponding interval graph represents each interval with a vertex. if they overlap then the intersection between the corresponding nodes is not null.

**The Question:**
If:- $IG$ is an interval graph: which contains a set of intervals {$i_1$,$i_2$,$i_3$,$i_4$,$i_5$} as shown in the diagram bellow.

[image]

How we can show that maximal independent set of this graph is also a maximum independent set at same time?

[image]

My suggestion: since I can find |IS| = 5 because there are no intersection between any intervals; and this is IS can't be extended as I draw them in the second graph:

Now How can I show that it is also maximum ? is it because no way to increase the maximal IS, so does this mean it must be Maximum IS ? I am still confusing to argue on my point view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Maximum Independent Set" is a "Maximal Independent Set" with the largest possible cardinality of vertices. Since the intervals are all disjoint, the resulting graph is also disjoint. Clearly the set of all vertices is a maximal independent set due to the disjointness. Clearly it is maximum because its cardinality is equal to the total number of vertices in the graph.

Comment: You are right, thank you !